# How can I resize my Mac boot partition?

Tags: partition, disk-space

I am having some problems using Disk Utility.

I am trying to combine all my partitions in to one (as it used to be), so that no space will be left unallocated. The problem is though my Recovery HD, it won't let me, it isn't letting me to do so. I can't increase my Mac HDD, but I can easily increase my Recovery HD.

[image: 1]

I don't how my Recovery HD is visible, that is a big mystery.

How can I get it as it used to be?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Could you clarify your situation? The Recovery HD is not normally shown in the partition view in Disk Utility — how are you able to resize it? With regards to how it 'used to be', are you attempting to hide the disk or did you make some change to your disk that you are unhappy with?

Comment: Thats confuses me also. I just want it to be as i used to be. 
I made an extra partition,  on primary which i installed linux on. I then deleted that partition, and somehow the i arent able to get all my memory back to one single partition, because my recoveryhdd blocks it now.http://snag.gy/KwuP0.jpg

Comment: I may have used linux to partition something, but can't see how that should've messed everything up?

Answer (score 1):

### [iPartition](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iPartition.php)

For all my partitioning, I use and recommend iPartition. It will allow you to resize partitions without deleting any data. **It will automatically move partitions if necessary to allow resizing into free space that is located after a second partition.**

> With iPartition, resizing a partition is as simple as selecting it, grabbing the resize handle and dragging. Not only that, but if you have several operations to perform, iPartition lets you queue them up and run them one after another, so you can have a cup of coffee while iPartition works. This feature, coupled with iPartition’s ability to automatically rearrange your existing partitions when necessary, makes iPartition the easiest partitioning tool that you’ll ever use.
>
> [image]

Comment: The weird part is i don't know why it appear at all,  i haven't made a prior recovery hdd, to one who is already on it from the begining.  I see it in finder and so, and aren't able to unmount it.   But should it supposed to be hidden. ?

Comment: And Ipartition isn't able to do it..

Answer (score 0):

Using Disk Utility tool

The primary partition can only be resized when all the other partitions - if existing - is deleted.
Take a backup of the existing non-primary partition is highly suggested as all the data on those existing partitions will be lost.

summarily - 
1. Take a back up of all the existing non-primary ( and primary too) partitions.
2. delete all the non-primary partition using Disk Utility tool.
3. resize the primary partition using Disk Utility tool.